# Access a variable defined inside a model's method in a controller.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've just started learning Ruby on Rails and I was wondering if there is a way by which I can access a variable defined in a model's method. I have a controller where I want to access the variable.
I have a model

```
class abc
 def score
  sum = 10
 end
end
```

And there is a controller

```
class FirstController < ApplicationController
 def get_score
 end
end
```

So I want to get the value of variable sum in method get_score. How can I achieve this?

Comment: you can get `score` using any object of class `abc`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an object [orientated programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) question; you're not calling a variable from your model, you're accessing either an attribute or an instance value (very important in terms of scoping etc) from a class.

--

You'll either need to make the variable a [*class* variable](http://apidock.com/rails/Class/cattr_accessor), invoke it as an instance method, or have class method to return it:

```
#app/models/model.rb
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
   cattr_accessor :sum #-> Model.sum class variable (static)
   @@sum = 10

   def self.sum
     10 #-> Model.sum class method (static)
   end
end
```

What you do depends on what type of data you're looking to return.

> - If the data is **static**, use a **class** method / variable
> - If the data is **dynamic**, use an **instance** method

Above is the code you'd use if you want to return a *static* value.

If you wanted to return a *dynamic* value, you'd use:

```
#app/models/model.rb
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
   def score
      self.games * self.goals # -> @model.sum instance method (dynamic)
   end
end
```

--

The difference is that if you use a *class* value, it is only available through initialization of the class. IE you can call `Model.sum` and have access to the record.

Instance methods / values are only accessible through an *instance* of the class:

```
@model = Model.find 5 #-> creates a new instance of the class
@model.sum #-> pulls the dynamic sum value of the class instance
```

---

## Fix

In your case, you'd be best using an **instance** method:

```
#app/models/abc.rb
class Abc < ActiveRecord::Base
   def score
      10
   end
end

#app/controllers/first_controller.rb
class FirstController < ApplicationController
   def get_score
      @abc = Abc.new
      @abc.sum #-> 10
   end
end
```

This way, your data will be dynamic, allowing you to manipulate it etc.

Answer (score 2):

In ruby method returns the last statement value if return statement is not return explicitly.
You can access the score as follows:

```
class FirstController < ApplicationController
 def get_score
      Abc.new.score
 end
end
```

Remember the class name is always starts with capital letter.

Answer (score 1):

In your `abc.rb` model file:

```
class Abc < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.score
    sum = 10
  end
end
```

Now you can access score method using Model name anywhere like.

```
class FirstController < ApplicationController
 def get_score
    Abc.score # you will get 10 here
 end
end
```